# How to plot curve properly in R?

Tags: r

I just started to learn R for my statistics class and I need to plot the curve with following parametrization:

[image]

I tried this, but not sure whether it's correct:

```
x <- seq(0,2*pi)
t <- choose(sin(2*x), cos(3*x) )
plot(t)
```

Because I get different curve on WolframAlpha

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use curve() to plot mathematical expression in R.

```
curve(choose(sin(2*x), cos(3*x)), from=0, to=2*pi)
```